# Function using array_multisort but don't know how to specify key

Tags: php, function, array-multisort

pretty new to PHP here but can't find info to help me on this.

Basically I'm writing a function to grab race times for horses on one day from my mysql database and order them. So I pull in 3 values - racedate, racevenue, and sectional. Sectional is so I can specify if I want their last 200m time, their last 400m time or so on.

I run the query and then put the result into an array. I then want to sort that array by the value of $sectional.

My problem is creating the array $times to use the array_multisort. The only way I can get it to work is to hardcode the 'time200' to specify what to sort on. I really want to be able to sort by the $sectional variable, so I can use this function on any type of column name passed in by $sectional (ie time200, time400, time600 etc).

Putting $sectional instead of time200 doesn't work (which is prob obvious to you who know more of what you're doing) but I can't figure out why.

Thanks for any help!

```
  function sectionalrank($racedate, $racevenue, $sectional) {
    global $connection;

    $query   = "SELECT horsename, $sectional ";
    $query  .= "FROM runs ";
    $query  .= "WHERE racedate = '$racedate' ";
    $query  .= "AND venue = '$racevenue' ";
    $query  .= "AND $sectional > 0";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    $times = array();
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        $times[] = $a['time200'];
    }

    array_multisort($times, SORT_ASC, $array);

    return $array;

  }
```

Comment: it would be better to sort you results straight from the query with an ORDER BY clause.  Also you should be using prepared statements for you query parameters. This code is wide open for sql injection .

Comment: ah of course! thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach appears to be good.  It works for me.

```
function sectionalrank( $racedate, $racevenue, $sectional )
    {
    // simulate database query
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 67, 'time200' => 2, 'time400' => 8);
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 86, 'time200' => 1, 'time400' => 3);
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 85, 'time200' => 6, 'time400' => 9);
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 98, 'time200' => 2, 'time400' => 1);
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 86, 'time200' => 6, 'time400' => 6);
    $racedata[] = array('horsename' => 67, 'time200' => 7, 'time400' => 4);

    $array = array();
    foreach ($racedata as $row)
        {
        $array[] = $row;
        }

    $times = array();
    foreach ($array as $a)
        {
        $times[] = $a[$sectional];
        }

    array_multisort($times, SORT_ASC, $array);
    return $array;
    }

// Using $racedata to pass in the data.
echo json_encode( sectionalrank( 'racedate', 'racevenue', 'time200' ) ) . "\n";
echo json_encode( sectionalrank( 'racedate', 'racevenue', 'time400' ) ) . "\n";

Output:
[{"horsename":86,"time200":1,"time400":3},{"horsename":67,"time200":2,"time400":8},{"horsename":98,"time200":2,"time400":1},{"horsename":85,"time200":6,"time400":9},{"horsename":86,"time200":6,"time400":6},{"horsename":67,"time200":7,"time400":4}]
[{"horsename":98,"time200":2,"time400":1},{"horsename":86,"time200":1,"time400":3},{"horsename":67,"time200":7,"time400":4},{"horsename":86,"time200":6,"time400":6},{"horsename":67,"time200":2,"time400":8},{"horsename":85,"time200":6,"time400":9}]
```

Comment: thanks, I used orangepills suggestion to use the ORDER BY in my query but this is also a help cheers